# Should Input Neurons have Input Weights?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

The output of an input neuron has a weight for every outgoing connection, so it seems that it would be redundant to have a weight for the input of the input neuron.  Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no weight applied before the outgoing weights. However, sometimes you may want to manipulate data before passing them through the first layer. That is called [preprocessing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_pre-processing).